# C - What's The Fastest Way To Get File Size?

Tags: c, file, size, cross-platform

After you have opened a file using:

```
const char *fMode = "r";
FILE *filePointer = fopen(location,fMode);
```

What's the fastest cross platform (Windows and Linux) way to get its size so you can allocate the right amount of memory using `malloc`?

I've seen that `ftell` only works if you open the file in binary mode.

Comment: define "fast"?  Ease of implementation?  runtime?  what's wrong with opening a file in binary mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `ftell`.

It's not 100% accurate, but it's good enough. Unless you are dealing with files that have only one or two characters per line, and LOTS of lines, the overhead is probably not important (sure, if the file has a million lines, AND the platform is Windows or something else where newline is more than one character, then there will be 1M extra bytes allocated. But if each line is, on average, 50 bytes long, you'll be allocating 50MB, so it's a 2% overhead).

The only alternative to `ftell` is to read every line in the file, and counting the number of characters. And if you want to read the file into memory, that's a pretty poor way to do it.

Suggestion of `stat` or `fstat`, or other similar functions will have exactly the same flaw of giving "the number of bytes the file takes up on disk, not the number of characters you'd read" [assuming, again, newlines are more than one character, which is the case on Windows and a few other OS's].

Answer (score 4):

You can find the size using `stat` or `fstat` before you open the file.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no way to tell exactly how much space a file will occupy in memory if you read the file in non-binary mode on a platform (like Windows) in which the end-of-line characters is more than one byte long.

Nonetheless, unless the file has lots of really short lines, the filesize returned by `ftell` or `fstat` will only be a little bit too big.